# Show there is an uncut square lying in a larger square cut by lines

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I found this problem on Keith Ball's blog sometime ago but I've never really worked it out.

[image]

> Show that if a square is cut by two lines (shown above in green) then
>   there is an uncut square at least one third as large (shown in red)
>   lying inside the original (and aligned with it).
>
> If this is too easy,
>   try it with three lines and an uncut square at least one quarter as
>   large as the original.

My first intuition was to use pigeonhole principle on a $3\times 3$ grid of equally sized squares, but one can clearly choose a sort of diagonal line passing through five squares. I don't think arguing by cases is particularly elegant and it may not be the inspired solution to the problem. Could anyone help?

Comment: You mean cut into pieces of same size, don't you?

Comment: @addy2012 Not necessarily, I think.

Comment: @Leg okay. these images were just so suggestive :)

Comment: @addy2012 But I would like to believe that equal areas of each piece would be sort of the worst case.

Comment: I mean, this is a special case of the "geometric pigeonhole principle" he describes as a corollary to the real planck principle in the DIscrete Geometry section here: https://keithmball.wordpress.com/current-research-interests/ Surely there's a more direct approach that he intended for this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let the large square have side length $3$. Note that in the figures of the OP appear two completely different limiting cases where no small square with side length $>1$ can be placed. Any proof will have to incorporate these cases somehow.

If there are no cutting lines we can move a small (unit) square along the inner boundary of the large square along a track of total length $8$. We shall show that a *single* cutting line $\ell$ leaves  a part of length $\geq4$ of this track available for the small square. It follows that two cutting lines cannot make all points of the track unavailable.

[image]

Place the large square with its center at the origin. By symmetry, it is enough to consider cutting lines $\ell$ given by an equation of the form $y=\tan\alpha \cdot x+c$ with $0\leq\alpha\leq{\pi\over4}$ and $c\geq0$. Such a line $\ell$ will cut $n\in\{0,1,2\}$ little corner squares (shaded grey in the above figures). The case $n=0$ is not drawn; the upper two figures show the case $n=1$, and the lower two figures show the case $n=2$. It is easily verified that in each case the pink squares can move freely along a total track length $\geq4$.